# the error it shows when I try to write a custom cmp function for sort(s, s+n, cmp)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

Originally I wrote a struct array which length is 10000 and each struct contains two integers. Then I try to use function sort() to sort them by variable "starttime". So I plan to rewrite a cmp function for sort(), then errors occurred.
Here are codes:

```
struct time
{
    int starttime=0;
    int endtime=0;
} original[10000];

bool cmpl(time a, time b){
    return a.starttime>b.starttime;
}

int readandinit(){
    int st=0, et=0, counter;
    while (cin>>st>>et){
        if (st<0||et<0) break;
        original[counter].starttime=st;
        original[counter].endtime=et;
    }
    sort(original, original+counter, cmpl);
}

int main(){
    readandinit();
}
```

it always shows me in "bool cmp(time a, time b)", there should be a ")" after "a" and a ";" after ")".
I can't find a way to solve it. Hope someone could help me to solve it.

Comment: You're missing a load of `#include`s for one.

Comment: Function [time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) exists...

Comment: `time` is not a very good choice of name for a struct if you are using `using namespace std`. Which is why you shouldn't do `using namespace std`. (You might be getting this error even without `using namespace std` but it is more likely with it). Your struct name clashes with the global function of the same name.

Comment: @Jarod42: Good spot!

Comment: @Jarod42 and n.'pronouns' m    Yes you are right, thanks a lot. Seems I've forgotten some basic programming principle...whatever, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Function [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) exists making the parsing not as expected, you might fix that by adding `struct`:

```
bool cmpl(struct time a, struct time b){
    return a.starttime > b.starttime;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a86fe7aaee3a026)

(or choosing another name)